# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта C# что это?

Tags: c#

[image: Скриншот]
Подскажите пожалуйста что это значит и как оно исправляется?

Comment: у Вас, видимо, `Training` в конфигурации не задан

Comment: Такое исключение выпадает, когда программа пытается обратиться к ссылочному объекту, который не инициализирован (не задано значение). Исправляется тем, что задается значение объекта, на котором вылетает исключение.

Answer (score 0):

Вангую `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Training"]` равно `null`. Исправляется добавлением проверки на `null` перед приведением `.ToString()`. Проверьте наличие `Training` параметра в конфигурации.